# Getting TOC to match Headings in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, table-of-contents

I have a Word 2007 document with headings as follows:

> 1.0  INTRODUCTION                                    (centered on top of page)
>   1.1  Terms of Reference
>   1.2  Dates of Inspection & Assessment
>
> 2.0  FIELD OBSERVATIONS                        (centered on top of page)
>   2.1  Terrain
>   2.2  Soil
>   2.3  Rainfall
>   2.4  Soil moisture deficit
>
> 3.0  RECOMMENDATIONS                            (centered on top of page)
>   3.1  abc
>   3.2  def
>   3.3  ghi

and so on.

How can I create a TOC in the formatting and numberings as shown above?  I tried "modify" and worked out "Heading 1" to give me "1.0". 2.0", etc. but "Heading 2" modification resulted in 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of 2.1), 1.4 (instead of 2.2) and so on.

Has anyone experienced the same issue and worked out a solution?

Comment: It isn't completely clear which of several problems you are actually trying to solve, but my guess is that you are trying to modify each Style separately, when you need to go into the Multilevel List Numbering dialog in Home->Paragraph (it's the 3rd icon along). For ToC paragraph layout you need to modify the built-in styles ToC 1, ToC 2 etc., but I would first verify that your style changes "stick" (they never used to).

Comment: Hi bibbadia, thank you very much for your valuable suggestion. I will try it out. The main issue is that I want the Heading 2 to remain as !.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, etc when i highlight them for generating TOC. But these end up as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, etc. when I modify the in-built Heading 2 style.  Thanks again.  Cheers!